# Using Allure framework with Selenium webdriver tests for better reporting.

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, test-report

I am using Selenium webdriver for automation. I have around 200 scripts ready and now i need a good reporting tool to generate reports. I recently heard about Allure framework, which is an open source tool and generates an amazing report.

Please guide me step by step on how to use Allure framework for better reporting of my scripts.

I need to generate a good report of my scripts which are ready. Thanks!

Comment: You may find essential information on the [official wiki.](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki) Also I suggest you to [watch video from Selenium Conf 14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrlS-7mLm0E) about that.

Comment: http://www.perfect-test.com/index.php/en/technologies-menu-en/technologies-other-menu-eng/38-allure-report-eng

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Allure has pretty good documentation to get started at: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/