# Allure reports do not generate results when calling mvn test with arguments

Tags: automated-testing, test-report, maven

If i run inside eclipse -> Run As -> Maven test, I have an allure-results directory created no problem in /target - Great!

If I call mvn from the command line and pass in some arguments.... I have no allure-results folder generated, I am very confused.

Why would some arguments not be resulting in successful build of allure-reports?

Instead of creating /allure-reports, when i pass in my arguments I can see instead a /cucumber-parallel directory, I assume there is a problem with my POM.XML?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>read-properties</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>src/test/resources/config.properties</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>src\test\resources\config.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
     <id>generateRunners</id>
     <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
     <goals>
       <goal>generateRunners</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
         <!-- Mandatory -->
         <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
         <glue>
          <package>webDriver</package>
          <package>censored</package>
          <package>censored2</package>
          <package>testRunner</package>
        </glue>
         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
          <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
           <featuresDirectory>src/test/java/</featuresDirectory>
          <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
          <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
          <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
          <format>json</format>
          <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
          <strict>true</strict>
          <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
          <monochrome>true</monochrome>
          <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like "@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
         <tags></tags>
         <!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags shall be generated. -->
         <filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
         <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. --> 
         <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
         <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' --> 
        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
        <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
        <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
        <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>


     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.6</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore> 
        <argLine>
         -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
         -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"
        </argLine>
        <properties>
        <property>
        <name>RunListener</name>
        <value>/src/test/java/testRunner/setupTeardown.java</value>
        </property>
        </properties>
            <forkCount>10</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.class</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
         <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
    </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            properties-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0-alpha-2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                read-project-properties
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.github.temyers
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [4.1.0,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I use `mvn clean test site` to generate Allure Reports. But I have "reporting" section in pom.xml

Comment: @dzieciou could you provide any more info about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Allure framework with Selenium webdriver tests for better reporting.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11585/using-allure-framework-with-selenium-webdriver-tests-for-better-reporting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was a mix up in the listeners used by maven surefire, when running as a standard test run inside maven it was referencing the allure reporter correctly, passing in arguments I was not correctly passing in the allure reporter as -Dcucumber.Options in mvn.

```
--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 
1. proper version of aspectjweaver with allure junit 
2. you have allure maven reporter. Example :

```
 <reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

this will create a folder structure on **mvn site** command which can be seen using jenkins allure plugins.

An example can be seen here 
[allure pom with junit](https://github.com/sarkershantonu/Automation-Getting-Started/blob/master/AllureJunit/pom.xml)